# Linux Mount using Remount to allow read-write

Tags: c++, linux

I want to remount a read-only file system so that it becomes read-write, using the root account.

Checking the Linux Manual pages, I noticed that there is no flag like MS_RDWRITE, so my question is, does anyone know of an example online that demonstrates using mount with remount flag that sets a read-only path to allow reading and writing?

This will be done in C++ for a device that runs embedded Linux.

```
/* Here's the declared function for Mount a filesystem.  */
extern int mount (__const char *__special_file, __const char *__dir,
      __const char *__fstype, unsigned long int __rwflag,
      __const void *__data) __THROW;
```

Comment: Remounting would involve unmounting (`umount()`) and mounting (`mount()`).  Omit the 'read only' flag to mount the file system in read-write mode.

Comment: Well, I would really prefer to make one call to mount using the MS_REMOUNT argument, like:  mount(NULL, "path_here", NULL, MS_REMOUNT, NULL);, but I am not sure what the last argument should be when MS_REMOUNT is specified.

Comment: "The meaning of data depends on the filesystem type and is controlled entirely by the filesystem driver in the kernel. " ref:  https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mount_002dUnmount_002dRemount.html

Comment: I have this same question posted to the manufacturer of the device. I guess I will try running it and hope I don't brick the device.

Comment: When I last looked at the manual page for `mount(2)` (7th Edition Unix — it's a long time since I worried about it),  it had 3 arguments.  It isn't standardized by POSIX.  The BSD version has 4 arguments (and the unmount operation is `unmount()`, not `umount()`). SVR4 `mount(2)` has some optional arguments — analogous to those in the Linux version, but different (the flags were 3rd).  Constant names for flags don't even have consistent prefixes (`MS_` vs `MNT_`).  It gets very system specific very quickly.  The only way to be sure is to find the right system-specific docs. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  And if you're dealing with a specific manufacturer's device, you have to know what their device driver expects.  With luck, a null pointer for the `data` argument would at worst tell you if you need to find a non-null value to pass instead (`errno == EINVAL` probably).  Any other value is risky until you know what's wanted.

Comment: OK thanks. I will wait for their help desk to respond. They are a big company and I have had good success with their tech. support in the past.

Comment: I did try using a null pointer to the data argument and the call returned without bricking the device, but I could not get it to work correctly, so I opted for the solution shown below. Thanks again for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the native API working.  Per the manufacturer, they recommended using the remount command in a terminal window. This worked correctly for me.

This will remount the entire root folder as read-write when called with root privileges.

```
        // Remount the root folder.         
        char* cmd = "mount -nwo remount,rw /";
        if (-1 == system(cmd))
        {
            // handle the error.
        }
```