# Remounting FS R/W under Linux

Tags: c++, filesystems, mount

I'm attempting to remount the filesystem on an embedded device both RW and RO, depending on the current situation.

[These](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) manpages show the function to use, and remounting the FS RO seems to be fairly trivial:

```cpp
    mount(nullptr, MOUNT_POINT.c_str(), nullptr, MS_REMOUNT | MS_RDONLY, nullptr);
```

However, the manpages fail to mention how to clear the RO flag so the FS is writable.
I've found several online posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62557536/linux-mount-using-remount-to-allow-read-write), but these either don't answer my question or propose an answer like using `system()`or `popen()` to call a shell command, which is **not** the answer I'm looking for.
That's a rather "icky" way of doing things, especially when it comes to error handling.

I have a feeling the answer is looking me right in the face, but it can't be as simple as omitting the MS_RDONLY flag, can it?
Or do I have to somehow fetch the flags and then AND them with MS_RDONLY to clear the bits?

Thanks in advance for helpful answers!

Comment: "It can't be as simple" - have you tried it? Because RW is the default. You don't "clear a flag", you pass the new flags when remounting.

Comment: To quote the man page section about remounting `The mountflags and data arguments should match the values used in the original mount() call, except for those parameters that are being deliberately changed.` So `rw` is just clearing the RDONLY flag. It's fetching the rest of the flags to match the previously used ones that may be a problem.

Comment: @dratenik Well damn. I completely overread that. I'll give it a try and report back.